# Limit of a ratio of functions using limit of ration of power series coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, limits, power-series

Suppose we want to find the following limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
\end{align}
and both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have power series represenations.
Is it correct to say that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ \sum_1^\infty a_n x^n}{\sum_1^N b_n x^n}\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}  \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{ \sum_1^N a_n x^n}{\sum_1^\infty b_n x^n}\\
&=  \lim_{N\to \infty}\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ \sum_1^N a_n x^n}{\sum_1^\infty b_n x^n}\\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{a_N}{b_N}
\end{align}

Is this justified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Counter example: $f(x)=e^x,g(x)=e^{-2x}$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$, but $f(x)=\sum\frac{x^k}{k!}$, $g(x)=\sum\frac{x^k}{k!}(-2)^k$, then $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_N}{b_N}=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{(-2)^N}=0$.